# Is it a good practice to allocate a Redux state dedicated to entity creation with a 'fire-and-forget' API?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, architecture, cqrs

In several blogs video and so on, there's a CRUD tutorial with Redux.

None of them (AFAIK after surfing) deal with fully async API on servers, like a **fire-and-forget** behavior.
Main **commands** in a **CQRS** environment deal frequently with those kind of fire-and-forget.

Let's take a fictive example of Twitter to easily get the idea:

Basically, in a context of a synchronous **CRUD API**, you likely have:

- Redux Action: **POST_TWEET**
- Server API: returning the entire created tweet in the response data.
- State: **TweetReducer** exploring and storing the created tweet's data from the response.
- UI: listening to the new tweet from the **Tweet** state directly.

The **TweetReducer**, besides the classical fetching APIs, can fully handle the **POST_TWEET** action since it can encompass the new tweet directly.

However, in a context of fire-and-forget API on the server:

- Redux Action: **POST_TWEET**
- Server API: returning only the tweet's id (e.g Location) in the response.
- State: **TweetReducer** does not handle the creation since the tweet is not available at the time of the success action triggering.
  Thus a new Redux state dedicated to handle tweet creation labeled **TweetCreation** typically owning those properties: (`data: {id: string}, inProgress: boolean, errors: []`).
  It would then grab the newly created tweet's id in the data and allow UI to listen to this state (**TweetCreation**).
- UI: listening to `TweetCreation` state and hence displays that the tweet is sent or even tries to fetch the server at some time interval to get the full tweet.

**Is it a good practice some people experiment to add another state on the Redux store to deal with fire-and-forget APIs**?

Is it "conventional" in the community or is there another clever way?

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Creating a separate state for pending tweets

For a start, you'd need to change your `TweetCreation` to an array in case the user makes a second tweet before the first is confirmed.

So your shape would look like this: `{ pendingTweets: [], confirmedTweets: [] }`.

In `POST_TWEET`, you append the new tweet to `pendingTweets`.
In `SET_TWEET_ID`, you remove the matching tweet from `pendingTweets` and push it to `confirmedTweets`.

In your component, you probably do something like `confirmedTweets.concat(pendingTweets).map(...)`.

### 2. Use the same state for pending tweets

The shape will just be `{ tweets: [] }`.

In `POST_TWEET`, you append the new tweet to `tweets`.
In `SET_TWEET_ID`, you update the matching tweet in `tweets`.

In your component, you do `tweets.map(...)`.

## Conclusion

Using the same state for pending tweets seems like a simpler (and therefore better) approach.

#### Additional considerations (for both approaches)

- I left out details about avoiding direct state mutations when updating since that's very basic.
- You probably need to do something like generating a temporary id for the pending tweet and sending it back from the server so that you can find the matching tweet in `SET_TWEET_ID`.
- The temporary id can use a different object key (or use an additional flag) so that you can distinguish between a pending and a confirmed tweet in the component (eg. to render a loading icon beside pending tweets).
- Replacing `[]` with `{}` using id as object key might be better (depending on the exact requirements) but that's not the focus of this question.

Comment: Actually your solution does make sense when the tweet to be saved has the exact same shaped that the final fetched version. Imagine the case where fetching a saved tweet on the server brings complete distinct results, like translating all words in german for instance. You could not benefit of storing the whole tweet (from html form data directly) in pending_tweets since it would end up by revealing a wrong  final tweet state to the client.

Comment: If tweet had title, we could imagine client writing it down in lowercase, and the server transforming it to uppercase. It would not be the responsibility of the client to know about the default formatting rule of the client. Tweet should be displayed with uppercases without the need to overspecified in the client. If we set the tweet in pending_tweets as it, the client would have a not valid version.

Comment: I do not see how the 2 approaches make a difference in that case. You'd  probably be returning the entire new tweet instead of just the id, then override the matching tweet completely.

Comment: "the client would have a not valid version" what do you mean by this? Why is that desirable?

Comment: that’s all the point of my OP: command APIs in CQRS world do not return the values created entities. By valid, I meant, client would display lowercase by default instead of the expected default format as uppercase.

Comment: I'm still not getting it. So in approach 2, it'll be wrongly displayed as lowercase, and in approach 1, something different is going to happen? What is it?

Comment: In approach 1, you would need a fetch (GET call) to retrieve the tweets content otherwise if you want to be consistent (not rely on in-memory form-data content), your pending and confirmed tweets states would contain only the ids at first.

Comment: To make sure I figure out your whole solution, do you distinguish TweetCreation store’s state from Tweet store’s state? Or do you deal only with Tweet store’s state that would contain itself several fields regarding tweet creation?

Comment: In approach 1, there's no `TweetCreation` at all, only a single `tweets` state which is an array that contains both pending and confirmed tweets (with pending tweets missing the actual database id). Not sure why you mentioned the form's data; pending tweets are stored in Redux in both approaches?

Comment: Your approach is: Client writes a tweet through a form. A redux action is dispatched containing those form data. You then end up storing the whole tweet data (without id in this case, if id generation is server-side (another subject)). When creation is succeeded through corresponding action, you move the pending tweet to the confirmed with the id included. 

My thought is: How to deal when you cannot consider the form data as tweet content but has to fetch for it to grab it. And fetching needs id so you aren't able to fulfill pending_tweets.

Comment: Sorry I meant approach 2 in previous comment. So you are talking about approach 1 (which is your approach, except I use an array to allow multiple pending tweets)? If you cannot consider the form data as the final content, then why not return the server content together with the id? What do you gain from making a separate `GET`? And is this separate `GET` only done after confirmation? In that case you'd have the db id? By "confirmed" we are referring to the server responding with the db id thus confirming that the tweet has been stored in db successfully right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169953/discussion-between-mik378-and-riwu).